# What is $\int_{0}^{\pi} (a^2+1+2a \cos\theta)^{\frac{p-1}{2}}d\theta$?

Tags: integration, complex-analysis

I have tried the problem using $\theta\rightarrow\theta/2$, then taking $z=e^{i\theta}$ we get $\frac{1}{2i}\int_{|z|=1}\frac{(a^2+1+a\sqrt{z}+\frac{a}{\sqrt{z}})^{\frac{p-1}{2}}}{z}dz$.

Comment: For $a > 0$,
$$\int_0^\pi (a^2 + 2 a \cos t + 1)^{p - 1} dt = \\
\frac
  {{\sqrt \pi} \, \Gamma(p) \tan(\pi p) \,|a - 1|^{2 p - 1}}
  {\Gamma {\left( p + \frac 1 2 \right)} (a + 1)}
 \, {_2 \hspace{-1px} F_{\hspace{-1px} 1}}
  {\left( \frac 1 2, p; p + \frac 1 2; \frac {(a - 1)^2} {(a + 1)^2} \right)} - \\
\frac
  {\pi^{3/2} \sec(\pi p) \, (a + 1)^{2 p - 2}}
  {\Gamma(p) \,\Gamma {\left( \frac 3 2 - p \right)}}
 \, {_2 \hspace{-1px} F_{\hspace{-1px} 1}}
  {\left( \frac 1 2, 1 - p; \frac 3 2 - p; \frac {(a - 1)^2} {(a + 1)^2} \right)}.$$

Comment: can you give more compact value? Also please explain the in between steps

Answer (score 0):

With the change of variables $t = 2 \arccos \sqrt u$,
$$\int_0^\pi (a^2 + 2 a \cos t + 1)^{(p - 1)/2} dt = \\
|a - 1|^{p - 1} \int_0^1 u^{-1/2} (1 - u)^{-1/2}
 \left( 1 + \frac {4 a} {(a - 1)^2} u \right)^{(p - 1)/2} du = \\
\pi |a - 1|^{p - 1} {_2 \hspace{-1px} F_{\hspace{-1px} 1}} {\left(
 \frac 1 2, \frac {1 - p} 2; 1; -\frac {4 a} {(a - 1)^2} \right)},
\quad a, p \in \mathbb R, \; a^2 \neq 1.$$